# SQL - joining 2 subqueries of total and weekly total

Tags: sql, mysql, subquery, left-join

I need to create a report with total sales and sales in the last 7 days for each salesman in a given department.  I have a table that lists for each sale the date, amount and ID of the salesman, and another table that maps salesmen into departments.

How can I have both the weekly and total sums show in a single query?

The query for each is:

```
SELECT user_id,sum(amount) AS total_amount
FROM sales 
LEFT JOIN users 
ON sales.user_id = users.id 
WHERE users.department = 1
GROUP BY user_id
```

and

```
SELECT user_id,sum(amount) AS total_amount 
FROM sales 
LEFT JOIN users 
ON sales.user_id = users.id 
WHERE users.department = 1 AND date > (NOW()-INTERVAL 1 WEEK) 
GROUP BY user_id
```

I can do this creating a view for one of the tables, but since I only need records for a given department (there are many), using a view that will generate results for all departments seems inefficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a way to query both with one table scan:

```
SELECT  user_id
,       sum(amount) as total
,       sum(case when date > (NOW()-INTERVAL 1 WEEK) then amount end) as weekly
FROM    sales
LEFT JOIN 
        users
ON      sales.user_id = users.id
WHERE   users.department = 1
GROUP BY 
        user_id
```

This uses a `case` to filter older rows out of the second `sum()`.